# How to vertical-align label and select?

Tags: html, css

```css
.customer_form label {
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.selectIcon {
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#topGroup {
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  width: 280px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#topGroup option {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer_form">
  <label for="topGroup">Category</label>
  <div class="selectIcon">
    <select id="topGroup">
      <option>Item1</option>
      <option>Item2</option>
      <option>Item3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using this dropdown on IE8 and need to use custom icon that is why I hidden default dropdown arrow icon.

However, when I hidden the icon the position of select will move up a little bit in firefox,chrome, ie

What can I do to make label and select have correct position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This     `vertical-align: middle;` on `.selectIcon` class

```css
.customer_form label {
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.selectIcon {
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle; //added
}
#topGroup {
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  width: 280px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#topGroup option {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer_form">
  <label for="topGroup">Category</label>
  <div class="selectIcon">
    <select id="topGroup">
      <option>Item1</option>
      <option>Item2</option>
      <option>Item3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

just add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.selectIcon` in css.

Answer (score 2):

You can add line-height: 34px to the label (same as height of the select). To make this work, you need to also add float: left and display: inline-block;

```css
.customer_form label {
  width: 80px;
  margin-right:15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  float: left;
  line-height: 34px; 
  display: inline-block;
}


.selectIcon {
  border-radius: 6px;
  height:30px;
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width:250px;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#topGroup {
  background: url(../images/00_arrorw_drop_darkgrey.png) no-repeat right;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  width: 280px;
  border:none;
  margin-top:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#topGroup option {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer_form">
        <label for="topGroup">Category</label>
          <div class="selectIcon">
            <select id="topGroup">
              <option>Item1</option>
              <option>Item2</option>
            <option>Item3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```